# Minecraft animation issue

Tags: animation, import, world

I'm trying to learn how to make Minecraft animations with blender, but I have 2 problems! If I try to import my Minecraft skin, it won't show the outer layer. It will only show the body! And also, I don't know how to move a specific block in my imported Minecraft world! It will grab the whole world instead of grabbing that specific block I selected!

Comment: Hello maybe make sure that the outer layer has its normals correctly flipped?As for the grabbing a specific block, are they separate objects in Blender? Is it not rather a question about Minecraft?

Comment: @moonboots What do you mean by "Maybe make sure that the outer layer has its normals correctly flipped?" I'm sorry but I'm kind of a noob, lol. Although I use a website called skindex editor to edit my skins! Maybe that will give you some information? And yes, it is a blender question. If I try to click on the arrow in my imported Minecraft world to see more, there's a bunch of blocks I can click on but it grabs the whole world... show all of the blocks. I would think the blocks would be separate  objects, but it grabs the whole world.

Comment: What does it give if you select the outer layer in Edit mode and press Alt N > Flip Normals?

Comment: Sorry about my last comment... I meant to edit it, but I accidently made it public so sorry for some of my bad grammar! Oh wait... Now that I think about it, I do see this little black outer layer that I always delete because some video told me too... Maybe that's my problem... Let me check!

Comment: Or please share your file (only keep the object that has the problem)

Comment: I figured out why my skin didn't have an outer layer! Now I can have an outer layer on my skin with blender :)! Thanks you so much!!!! But do you know how to help with the moving blocks thing?